# Solving Dirac delta double integrals

Tags: calculus, stochastic-integrals, dirac-delta

I am solving a stochastic ODE with additive noise:

$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = -\alpha x(t) + L(t)$

where L(t) is Gaussian noise meaning $<L(t)> = 0,
<L(s)L(t')> = 2D\delta(s -t').$

I am trying to calculate $<x^2(t)>$ but I am getting confused by the resulting double integral:

$2D\int_0^tds e^{-\alpha(t-s)} \int_0^tdt'e^{-\alpha(t-t')}\delta(s-t')$
which should equate to $\frac{D}{\alpha}(1-e^{-2\alpha t})$.

Do you use the fact $\delta(s-t')$ = $\delta(t'-s)$.Then apply the following property:
$\int_{\omega}dzf(z)\delta(z-z_0) = f(z_0)$ when $\omega$ includes the point $z_0$ to get
$\int_0^tds e^{-2\alpha(t-s)}$ ? Our lecturer didn't cover these steps and they give very blunt replies so I just wanted to get some alternative response. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you should do.